# Don't know how to extracting two-dimensional arrays in three dimensions C

Tags: c

This is my void:

```
struct MateMessage newMate(char** cr){ ...... }
```

And this is my  three dimensions args:

```
char args[3][3][3]
```

-------The each slot of 'args' if not NULL.---------

And I do like this:

```
 newMate(args[1])
```

This is what I get:
**[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'newMate' from incompatible pointer type**

If you need more message please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that `NULL` is for null *pointers*. Only pointers can be `NULL`. You array `args` can't be `NULL` since it's not a pointer, and neither is any of the values in `args`.

Answer (score 1):

`args[1]` is an array of arrays, and an array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer.

It can however decay to a pointer to arrays. In your case `args[1]` will decay to the type `char (*)[3]`. Which is the type you need to use for the argument:

```
struct MateMessage newMate(char (*cr)[3]){ ...... }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a function accepting an array of type `char args[3][3][3]`, simply use this:

```
struct MateMessage newMate(char args[3][3][3])
```

Or in case the dimensions should be variable:

```
struct MateMessage newMate(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, char args[x][y][z])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a one-dimensional array is much like a pointer to an array element, a multi-dimensional array is not a pointer to a pointer... or an array of pointers. In memory it is organized like a one-dimensional array, the only difference is that the compiler knows how to calculate the address from more than one index.

Your array is organized in memory like this

```
a000 a001 a002 a010 a011 a012 a020 a021 a022 a100 a101 a101 ...
```

where `a[0][0][0]` etc. is written as `a000` etc. to save space. You can do

```
newMate(args[1])
```

if you define `newMate` to take a two-dimensional array

```
struct MateMessage newMate(char cr[3][3]) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            doSomethingWith(cr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return something;
}
```

In this case function the caller will pass the address of `a[1][0][0]` to `newMate` and `newMate` will know how to address the remaining two dimensions.